# Convert string value to Float in C#.net

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a string variable called `strFloatvalues` and I'm assigning value to this variable by fetching from the database table. In my table, the values are 10f,20f,30f.
I am reading table value and assigning to my string variable.

```
strFloatValues = "10f,20f,30f";
```

Now my requirement is i want to convert above string data into float array like

```
float[] fArray = new float[] { 10f,20f,30f };
```

I tried below code it is throwing exception line unable cast.

```
float[] floatarray = Array.ConvertAll(sValues.Split(','), new Converter<string, float>(float.Parse));
```

Comment: Yes, because `float.Parse` doesn't accept a suffix at the end. You could use `x => float.Parse(x.TrimEnd('f'));` as your converter to fix this, although that will then accept "10ffff" for example, which you might not want to.

Comment: You are storing `10f,20f,30f.` as a single value in your database? That should be three floats instead of one varchar